# Node.js: How to read data from stream using .read()

Tags: node.js, stream, buffering, readable

**Model:** The user selects a mp4 file from his mobile on a static page hosted by a node.js express server on the same network, the file stream is received by busboy in the same server. Now the file stream has to be read in parts/segments/buffers and sent ahead through websocket to be added to the MediaSource buffer on the other screen.

**Question:** How to read x numbers of bytes of data from a paused readable stream?

**Code(not working):**

```
function ReadData(stream, BytesToRead){
     stream.resume();
     var data = stream.read(BytesToRead);
     stream.pause();
     return data;
}
```

Kindly help!

Comment: What is — not — working?

Comment: It is returning null

Comment: Sorry. I am — not — experienced as much. [But I guess you need `data` from somewhere.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_data)